# Why is the "new" label so hard to read?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I suspect some CSS rule is being incorrectly applied to the "new" feature notifier.

I'm talking about the "new" block that appears when a new navigation or other site element is added. It showed up most recently on the main site when the blog link was added.

[image: It's NEW!]

The e is nearly solid, and the rest of the text just looks... off. Any ideas why?

Additionally, as provided by @stuffe, As well as being blocky, it's not aligned to the text baseline.

[image: Text baseline example]

Comment: It's even worse on my screen, agree it needs loooking at.

Comment: I suspect that this question made Jeff realize that the link was not here on meta, since it's suddenly here, and "new"! Which was not the case last night when I wrote this up.

Comment: I found that removing the CSS shadow on that text helps. http://i.imgur.com/b8qij.png

Comment: I figured that might be the case. Definitely looks much more readable.

Comment: it's a problem with text-shadow. i'll remove it for this site.

Comment: Can this be marked as answered?

Comment: I will review that tomorrow when a blog post goes up.

Comment: Erm, no, this can't be marked as answered, because there is no answer. [edit] But there is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Screenshot of Jin's text comment. (Yes, really.)]